# anyone know of a perl compression method that equals winrar consistency?

Tags: perl, zip

is archive::ZIP consistent enought to trust the file will always be the exact same size byte for byte?
i am trying to check for file consistency and compressing the file tells me if there is data in the file. so isarchive::zip consistent to achive same filesize everytime?

the files i am doing this check on are encryted with a random key for every single file btw. guess i shoul;d have mentioned that earlier ;0

Comment: i guess what im saying is you can have a file that is 10 MB but if its full of 00's then it will compress it down to almost anything. if there is actually data in the file. then it will compress it to a certain filesize everytime.

Comment: It seems you're trying to [estimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_estimation) the [entropy/information content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) of a file. In that case, using a compression algorithm for the estimation is tricky because these algorithms are far from perfect (but that's a problem with any estimation strategy). If you are just trying to detect whether two files are the same or whether a file has been corrupted, use a fast hash function e.g. from the [SHA-2 family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) instead.

Comment: its encrypted data and it uses random signatures for every different file xD

Comment: If the files have been encrypted *properly* (i.e. simply XOR-ing with a key doesn't count), then the resulting output should have a seemingly very high entropy, i.e. appear absolutely random and shouldn't compress at all. So attempting compression wouldn't tell you how much information the original content held. What are you actually trying to do exactly?

Comment: just do some basic file checks to make sure the data is there and a bunch of pattern searchings. the file is randomly signed for each file version and does have very high entropy and looks completely random. i just need some ways to check the files to be honest i had a friend tell me a few ways but we have already covered them ie high entropy doesnt compress hardly at all IF any and repeated pattern searching. but yes they are very... very random ;D but full of data

Comment: also like i said man these are basic file checks because there is no way to actually decrypt the file to actually do a generic hash check. if i could do that i would have not made this thread ;)

Comment: any other methods of making it more "trusting" even tho its randomly encrypted data?

Comment: So you need to verify that an encrypted file will come out the same on the other end? If you need to verify the plaintext content, then there is no way to do this without decrypting it first. However, you can run a digest on the encrypted content on one machine, send the files somewhere else, and then run the digest on the other machine, again against the encrypted content.

Comment: its multiple files of the same data.... byte for byte. if i /was/ able to decrypt it i would be able to just do a hash check.but even tho its the exact same data in every file... its encrypted differently and without knowing the key for each and every single file to decrypt the data... i need a way to "help" make me feel better about its validity ;)

Comment: entropy and pattern searching is all i can think of. if anyone has any other ideas it would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: also i just figured out that archive::zip is NOT suitable for doing this. winrar however will produce the same filesize over multiple files when they are compressed. the problem isthere are different revisions of the file. some files are just a little bigger than others. hopefully that helps someway for you to understand lol

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking if, for instance, a 10MB file of arbitrary data will always compress down to 5MB?

No compression algorithm will make those guarantees (though there are some snake oil peddlers that might). Lossless compression works by finding patterns in the data and putting them into a more compact form. Purely random data cannot be compressed, because there are no patterns in it. In between the extremes of pure randomness and a file full of zeros, it all depends on how good your algorithm is at finding patterns. There are theoretical limits on how good this can be.

As a rule, the more data you put into the algorithm, the more chances it has to find patterns, and therefore the end compression ratio will be better. In a Zip archive, each file is compressed individually and then archived together into a single file. This gives a lower overall compression ratio, but it also means that a random bit error early in the file doesn't corrupt the whole thing.

Tarballs and (I believe) RAR work inside-out from that; they archive first, then compress. This gets you a better ratio with the tradeoff of error correction going awry.

Comment: updated original question, thanks for the info though